# How to change audio output when subscribe to a audio streaming OpenTok - ReactNative

Tags: react-native

I'm making a voice call in `ReactNative` `App` with [`Opentok ReactNaitve SDK`](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-react-native).

Does anyone know how I can switch between earpiece and speaker (mobile phone) when subscribing to a audio streaming?

Comment: Any success? I am struggling with the same, even tried with default AVAudioSession

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have written native functions for both platforms on this issue.
Currently, I haven't figured out a better way to resolve it, so you can try my way.

I think you already know How to write a native module for [android](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android) and [iOS](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios) platforms, so I will only give you the main stuff.

For iOS:

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(switchAudioOutput: (BOOL *)isSpeckerPhoneOn) {
  NSError* error;
  AVAudioSession* session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

  [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&error];
  [session setMode:AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat error:&error];
  RCTLogInfo(@"Setting audio output");
  if (isSpeckerPhoneOn) // Enable speaker
  {
    [session overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker error:&error];
    RCTLogInfo(@"Enable Speaker");
  }
  else // Disable speaker
  {
    [session overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone error:&error];
    RCTLogInfo(@"Disable Speaker");
  }
  [session setActive:YES error:&error];
}
```

For Android:

```
@ReactMethod
    public void switchAudioOutput(Boolean isSpeckerPhoneOn) {
        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)this.mContext.getSystemService(this.mContext.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        if (isSpeckerPhoneOn) {
            audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
        } else {
            audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
        }
    }
```

I hope it will help you get out of stuck. Good luck!